# SQL Server: Join tables in a loop going through table rows

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with the following fiels: **PicklistTable**, **PicklistColumnName**, **FormTable** and **FormColumnName**. FormColumnName is a foreign key into PicklistTable that I need to join on PicklistColumnName. 
Basically I need to find out how many times each picklist values has been used on all forms that reference that picklist. So the query would look something like this (maybe??):

```
SELECT PicklistColumnName, count(FormColumnName1) + count(FormColumnName2) as Count
FROM PicklistTable
INNER JOIN FormTable1 ON PicklistColumnName = FormColumnName1
INNER JOIN FormTable2 ON PicklistColumnName = FormColumnName2
GROUP BY PicklistColumnName
```

Here is an example table:

```
    PicklistTable   PicklistColumnName  FormTable        FormColumnName 
tblEthnicityValues  Ethnicity_ID    tblContact          Contact_Ethnicity_ID
tblEthnicityValues  Ethnicity_ID    udfOHFTCYPLACIHAC   FatherEthnicityID
tblEthnicityValues  Ethnicity_ID    udfOHFTCYPLACIHAC   MotherEthnicityID
tblEthnicityValues  Ethnicity_ID    udfOHFTCYPLACIHAYP  EthnicityID
tblEthnicityValues  Ethnicity_ID    udfOHFTCYPLACIHAYP  FatherEthnicityID
tblEthnicityValues  Ethnicity_ID    udfOHFTCYPLACIHAYP  MotherEthnicityID
tblEthnicityValues  Ethnicity_ID    udfOHFTCYPLACRHAC   FatherEthnicityID
tblEthnicityValues  Ethnicity_ID    udfOHFTCYPLACRHAC   MotherEthnicityID
```

So I would in this case need to join tblContact, udfOHFTCYPLACIHAC etc on Contact_Ethnicity_ID, FatherEthnicityID etc.

Can someone please help? I hope I explained it well enough.

Thanks!
Tanya

Comment: This sounds like a really horrible design. You have designed yourself into being forced to use dynamic sql for everything. This pretty much defeats the point of using relational database. If you really want some help here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid this design won't take you where you want to go.  You just don't want to do this in dynamic SQL.  If you have the option to redesign the database structure, do so.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do anything with the database...this doesn't sound very promising... :(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `PicklistColumnName` from `PicklistTable` table need not be present in both `FormTable1` and `FormTable2` tables, this query might solve your problem.

```
SELECT pt.PicklistColumnName, count(ft1.FormColumnName1) + count(ft2.FormColumnName2) as Count
FROM PicklistTable pt
LEFT OUTER JOIN FormTable1 ft1 
ON pt.PicklistColumnName = ft1.FormColumnName1
LEFT OUTER JOIN FormTable2 ft2 
ON pt.PicklistColumnName = ft2.FormColumnName2
GROUP BY pt.PicklistColumnName
```

Comment: Hi Venu, Thanks for your answer, the problem is that the amount of tables I need to join will be different depending on the picklist I am looking at. I first look for all tables that reference this picklist and put the table names in a temporary table. I think I would need some king of loop in this case that would join a FormTable table for each row in my temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

Do  you want to get the following SQL:

```
DECLARE @tb TABLE(PicklistTable VARCHAR(30),PicklistColumnName VARCHAR(30),FormTable VARCHAR(30),FormColumnName VARCHAR(30) )
INSERT INTO @tb(PicklistTable,PicklistColumnName,FormTable,FormColumnName)
    SELECT 'tblEthnicityValues','Ethnicity_ID','tblContact','Contact_Ethnicity_ID' UNION
    SELECT 'tblEthnicityValues','Ethnicity_ID','udfOHFTCYPLACIHAC','FatherEthnicityID' UNION
    SELECT 'tblEthnicityValues','Ethnicity_ID','udfOHFTCYPLACIHAC','MotherEthnicityID' UNION
    SELECT 'tblEthnicityValues','Ethnicity_ID','udfOHFTCYPLACIHAYP','EthnicityID' UNION
    SELECT 'tblEthnicityValues','Ethnicity_ID','udfOHFTCYPLACIHAYP','FatherEthnicityID' UNION
    SELECT 'tblEthnicityValues','Ethnicity_ID','udfOHFTCYPLACIHAYP','MotherEthnicityID' UNION
    SELECT 'tblEthnicityValues','Ethnicity_ID','udfOHFTCYPLACRHAC','FatherEthnicityID' UNION
    SELECT 'tblEthnicityValues','Ethnicity_ID','udfOHFTCYPLACRHAC','MotherEthnicityID'
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(max)
SELECT @sql='SELECT '+t.PicklistColumnName+',(0'+t.subCountSQL+') AS'+CHAR(13)+'Count FROM '+t.PicklistTable+CHAR(13)+t.subSQL FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT PicklistTable,PicklistColumnName,t2.* ,t3.*
    FROM @tb AS t1
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT 'INNER JOIN '+FormTable+' ON PicklistColumnName='+tt.FormTable+'.'+tt.FormColumnName+' '
                FROM @tb AS tt WHERE tt.PicklistTable=t1.PicklistTable AND tt.PicklistColumnName=t1.PicklistColumnName
                FOR XML PATH('')
    ) AS t2(subSQL)
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT '+COUNT('+tt.FormTable+'.'+tt.FormColumnName  +')'
                FROM @tb AS tt WHERE tt.PicklistTable=t1.PicklistTable AND tt.PicklistColumnName=t1.PicklistColumnName
                FOR XML PATH('')
    ) AS t3(subCountSQL)

)AS t 
PRINT @sql
EXEC(@SQL)
```

The variable @SQL will be :

```
 SELECT Ethnicity_ID,(0+COUNT(tblContact.Contact_Ethnicity_ID)+COUNT(udfOHFTCYPLACIHAC.FatherEthnicityID)+COUNT(udfOHFTCYPLACIHAC.MotherEthnicityID)+COUNT(udfOHFTCYPLACIHAYP.EthnicityID)+COUNT(udfOHFTCYPLACIHAYP.FatherEthnicityID)+COUNT(udfOHFTCYPLACIHAYP.MotherEthnicityID)+COUNT(udfOHFTCYPLACRHAC.FatherEthnicityID)+COUNT(udfOHFTCYPLACRHAC.MotherEthnicityID)) AS Count FROM tblEthnicityValues
 INNER JOIN tblContact ON PicklistColumnName=tblContact.Contact_Ethnicity_ID INNER JOIN udfOHFTCYPLACIHAC ON PicklistColumnName=udfOHFTCYPLACIHAC.FatherEthnicityID INNER JOIN udfOHFTCYPLACIHAC ON PicklistColumnName=udfOHFTCYPLACIHAC.MotherEthnicityID INNER JOIN udfOHFTCYPLACIHAYP ON PicklistColumnName=udfOHFTCYPLACIHAYP.EthnicityID INNER JOIN udfOHFTCYPLACIHAYP ON PicklistColumnName=udfOHFTCYPLACIHAYP.FatherEthnicityID INNER JOIN udfOHFTCYPLACIHAYP ON PicklistColumnName=udfOHFTCYPLACIHAYP.MotherEthnicityID INNER JOIN udfOHFTCYPLACRHAC ON PicklistColumnName=udfOHFTCYPLACRHAC.FatherEthnicityID INNER JOIN udfOHFTCYPLACRHAC ON PicklistColumnName=udfOHFTCYPLACRHAC.MotherEthnicityID
```